# VBA Get specific differences in hours

Tags: vba, date, difference, hour

I'm having trouble in getting the detailed or specific differences between two dates in minutes. Let's say:

```
Date Start : 24/7/2015  12:38:00 PM
Date End   : 27/7/2015  12:12:00 PM
```

My code did give the differences between both date but actually does not specific, which means it gives difference of 3 days between both date, but not just I want (Let's say their difference is 68hours 30minutes 56seconds). So, how can I do this?

Here is my code :

```
Date1 = DateValue(CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "U").Value)
Date2 = DateValue(CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "S").Value)

FRow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
lrow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows(CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row

For PRow = lrow To 2 Step -1
    CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AD").Value = DateDiff("d", Date2, Date1) 'produce days
    CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AE").Value = DateDiff("h", Date2, Date1) 'produce hours
    CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AF").Value = DateDiff("n", Date2, Date1) 'produce minutes
Next PRow
```

Currently the answer I got :

> 3 days,
>
> 72hours (3 times 24hours),
>
> 1440minutes (24hours times 60minutes).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, it's simple! I never thought of this way could produce the answer just like I want! :)

Dim FRow As Long
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim PRow As Long

```
Range("AD1").Value = "Hours Differences"

Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Set CurrentSheet = Excel.ActiveSheet

FRow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
lrow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows(CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row

For PRow = lrow To 2 Step -1
CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AD").Value = (CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "U").Value - CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "S").Value) * 24
Next PRow
```

It will produce 71.5666666666511. I was distracted by DATE format. Thanks all for those helps! :D

Comment: Just add CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AD").Value = Round(((CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "U").Value - CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "S").Value) * 24) , 2) to change into 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you have used function `DateValue` that converts a value to date only (time part is removed).

So, those dates:

```
Date Start : 24/7/2015  12:38:00 PM
Date End   : 27/7/2015  12:12:00 PM
```

after processing them with `DateValue` function became:

```
Date Start : 24/7/2015  00:00:00
Date End   : 27/7/2015  00:00:00
```

---

[EDIT]

You need to convert them to `Date` type.

You can use VBA built-in function `CDate` to do that:

```
Date1 = CDate(CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "U").Value)
Date2 = CDate(CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "S").Value)
```

Comment: So, into what type I must convert to?

Answer (score 0):

Internally, dates are stored as number of days since Jan-1-1900 (or 1902, in does not really matter). That means `1 day = 1`, that also means `1 hour  = 1/24`.
So if I understand your question correctly, to get the difference in days, hours, minutes between date2 and date1, you could use

```
daysdiff = DateDiff("d", Date2, Date1)
hoursdiff = INT((Date2-date1-Daysdiff)/24)
'or
hoursdiff = DateDiff("h", Date2-daysdiff, Date1)
minutesdiff = Datediff("n", Date2-daysdiff-hoursdiff/24, Date1)
```

Sorry, not tested, but you get the idea.

---

Edit: you should also include @mielk remarks in you changes.